# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment in jar file

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mq

I got this error when running a maven built jar file:

I build my jar file using maven on NetBean, I able to run without issue on my Netbean, but when I run the jar file java -jar SimpleTestMQ-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar this error happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/mq/MQEnvironment
        at com.stee.simpletestmq.SimpleTestApp.main(SimpleTestApp.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: What version of MQ Java client are you using? You seem to be missing MQ Java client in the path. Can you try  "java -cp <path where MQ Java client is located>/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar -jar SimpleTestMQ-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: @Shashi: that won't help; `-jar` sets the classpath only from the manifest in the jar and ignores any option `-cp` or envvar `CLASSPATH`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: C:\Users\commonuser\.m2\repository\com\stee\SimpleTestMQ\1.0-SNAPSHOT>java -jar C:\Users\commonuser\.m2\repository\com\ibm\mq\com.ibm.mq.allclient\9.2.5.0\com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.2.5.0.jar -jar SimpleTestMQ-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Invalid command line option '-jar'. Use java -jar com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar -help for usage information.
Name:        IBM MQ classes for Java Message Service
Version:     9.2.5.0
Level:       p925-L220207
BuildType:   Production [Built on IBM Corporation  8.0.5.17 -

Comment: Two choices: either 'fat jar' with e.g. Maven Shade or proper full  classpath *without* `-jar`